# Replace value in Excel table if three other attributes all match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a forecasting tool, and our price list does not always reflect negotiated pricing. I'm hoping to use VBA to replace values Table 1 (forecasting data) with the values in Table 2 (negotiated values).

My approach would be to use VBA to try to find rows in Table 1 whose Customer, PO #, and Product attributes match to a row in Table 2, and, if there is a match, replace the Value in Table 1 with the Value in Table 2.

I'm a novice with VBA and can usually write simple procedures or modify code I find online, but I'm not quite sure how to pull off this specific task, and I could really use some help. Any suggestions are appreciated!

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Why not use SUMIFS based on those criteria to find the Value from Table 2?

Comment: This would be a perfect formula. The issue here is that I don't want to replace all the values. Notice that Table 2 does not contain all of the item combinations in Table 1.

Comment: Look [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria), that should give you a hint in the right direction

Comment: Make a helper column and nest an if statement with the sumifs. E.g. `if(IfError(Sumifs(),0)>0,Sumifs(),RangeWithExistingValue)`

Comment: Will the value in Table 2 ever be 0?

Comment: @bigben, no the value will be > 0

Comment: Then if SUMIFS returns 0 (that particular item combination doesn't exist in Table 2), return the original value from Table 1.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Thank you! I'd prefer not to add columns to the data set. Is there a way to insert the sumifs formula into the dataset only if the three attributes match?

Comment: Don't you have to account for month? Or do you replace every instance based on match in the other columns with the same forecasted value?

Comment: @QHarr, price is determined by customer, item, and PO#, and it is consistent across months for these attributes.